# As of 2017-09, Has there been talks or test implementations of making Litecoin anonymous / untracable like Monero or Zcash?

Tags: litecoin, privacy, traceability, zcash, monero

Being that Litecoin is more likely to implement experimental features before Bitcoin. As of today 2017-09, has there been discussions or test implementations of making Litecoin anonymous like Monero's Ring Signatures or adopt similar features like Zcash?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Increasing fungibilty is a goal, there have been several proposals of differing seriousness and support. But this is generally seen as a goal for the project.

That being said, BTC/LTC simply cannot ever achieve this goal as throughly as Monero has without a complete redesign, which will not happen.